# Why no PGAdmin in launcher for standard user?

Tags: launcher, users, administration, privileges, postgresql

I have installed PGAdmin and it all works well. But when I log in as a Standard User on Ubuntu 12.04 I don't see PGAdmin in the launcher. I have other programs like Libre Office, Lazarus and TeamViewer in the launcher but not PGAdmin.

Is there a reason why this is happening and what I can do to allow this?

Thanks!

Comment: Icons like pgadmin will only be in the launcher if you put it manually there.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to open dash and type pgadmin and run the program.

The path to PGAdmin was found like this:

```
which pgadmin3
```

And this pointed to the `/usr/bin` directory.